# I get error when i run testng with maven using selenium

Tags: maven, selenium, testng

I am having issue running Page Factory with maven using selenium and will appreciate if someone could assist with this. When i run the TestPage class, i get the below error:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [SelectCourse] with [interface org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver].
For more information on native dependency injection please refer to http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection
```

```
package pageObjectFactoryMaven;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class SelectCoursePage {

    WebDriver driver;
    public SelectCoursePage (WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
    }

    @FindBy (id = "navBlue")
    WebElement studying;

    @FindBy (css = "element")
    WebElement findacourse;

    @FindBy ( id = "query")
    WebElement entersearchitem;

    public WebElement studying(){
        return studying;
    }

    public WebElement findacourse(){
        return findacourse;
    }

    public WebElement entersearchitem(){
        return entersearchitem;
    }
}
```

```
package pageObjectFactoryMaven;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class SignInPage {

    WebDriver driver;

    public SignInPage (WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    @FindBy (id ="MUA_CODE")
    WebElement enterusername;

    @FindBy (id ="PASSWORD" )
    WebElement enterpassword;

    @FindBy (name = "OK.DUMMY.MENSYS.1")
    WebElement clickLogin;

    public WebElement enterusername() {
        return enterusername;   
    }

    public WebElement enterpassword() {
        return enterpassword;
    }

    public WebElement clickLogin() {
        return clickLogin;
    }
}
```

```
package TestClass;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import pageObjectFactoryMaven.SelectCoursePage;
import pageObjectFactoryMaven.SignInPage;

public class TestPage {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup (){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("wwww.hhg.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void SelectCourse (WebDriver driver) {
        SelectCoursePage POF1 = new SelectCoursePage (driver);
        POF1.studying().click();
        POF1.findacourse().click();
        POF1.entersearchitem().sendKeys("computer science");    
    }

    @Test
    public void SignIn (WebDriver driver) {
        SignInPage POF2 = new SignInPage (driver);
        POF2.enterusername().sendKeys("kff");
        POF2.enterpassword().sendKeys("jdnd");
        POF2.clickLogin().click();     
    }
}
```

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>SeleniumExeterUni_POM</groupId>
  <artifactId>SeleniumProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>SeleniumProject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
        <jre.level>1.10</jre.level>
        <jdk.level>1.8</jdk.level>
    </properties>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.0</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>

     <build>
       <plugins>
                <!-- Compiler plug-in -->
         <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.level}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.level}</target>
                </configuration>


   </plugin>


          <!-- Below plug-in is used to execute tests -->
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>


                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <!-- TestNG suite XML files -->
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

       </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your test code. Your `@Test` method signature says that it needs a `WebDriver` object as a parameter, but you haven't told TestNG how should it go about finding an instance and then injecting it into your `@Test` method. TestNG on its own can only inject the below as parameters into your `@Test` method (which is what is called as **native injection**)

- `ITestResult` object which represents the test result.
- `Method` object which represents an actual method.
- `ITestContext` object which represents a `<test>` being executed.

More information on all these and much more can be found at the [official documentation site](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection).

To fix your problem, you have two ways of doing it.

1. Approach 1 (This will not let you run your tests in parallel)

Change your `@BeforeMethod` from

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setup (){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("wwww.hhg.com");
}
```

to something like this:

```
private WebDriver driver = null;

@BeforeMethod
public void setup (){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("wwww.hhg.com");
}
```

Your code was working with a local `WebDriver` variable in the `@BeforeMethod`. The altered one basically leverages a data member, and your `@BeforeMethod` just instantiates it. You also need to get rid of the `WebDriver` parameter from your `@Test` method.

2. Approach 2

You use the same details as mentioned in Approach 1, but you work with a ThreadLocal variant, instead of a regular `WebDriver` object. You can read more about working with ThreadLocal variables from my blog post [here](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/parallel-webdriver-executions-using-testng/).

Comment: I have tried the first approach and it didn't work ang got the same error. Thanks

Comment: @ Krishna Mahadevan private WebDriver driver = null;

@BeforeMethod
public void setup (){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("wwww.hhg.com");
}

Comment: What does your Test method look like and what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: I didn't make any changes to the Test method, as i don't understand the second approach you mentioned. The error i got was  - Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [SelectCourse] with [interface org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver].

Comment: You need to remove the `WebDriver` parameter from your `@Test` method. Your test method would now have to refer to the `WebDriver` from you class level attribute. I guess I had included that part also in my answer.

Comment: I have just done that and i updated the project by right clicking on project and did a maven update and got this error - org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot find class in classpath: TestClass.TestPage

Comment: @user9790882 - That's a different problem and its probably due to a messed up classpath. You should still be able to run your test from the command prompt (not the IDE) viz the command `mvn clean test -Dtest= TestPage`. Either ways, I think your original problem is resolved. Please go ahead and accept my answer, if it helped.

Comment: I still couldnt get it to work. Do you now how to add class to classpath. Thanks